# I can't use JSTL tag for read rss

Tags: jsp, jstl

I want to read rss from another web. but I can't read rss . I use Netbeans and I add JSTL Library already. I can use forEach tag but every time when I use xml tag it show error. This is my code for read rss. I don't know how to read rss with JSTL tag please help me.

---

```
<!-- Filename: ShowStudents.jsp -->
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<HTML>
<BODY>
<c:import var="xmlDoc" url="http://www.manager.co.th/RSS/Home/Breakingnews.xml"/>
<x:parse var="parsedDocument" xml="${xmlDoc}"/>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Title : </th>
<th>Link : </th>
</tr>

<x:forEach select="$parsedDocument/channel/item"> // This code I ever been change to $parsedDocument/rss/channel/ and $parsedDocument/rss/channel/title ,but it show same error. 
<tr>
<td> <x:out select="title" /> </td>
<td> <x:out select="link" /> </td>
</tr>
</x:forEach>
</table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

---

when I run this code it show error like this. how to read rss with JSTL tag please help me.

> description The server encountered an
>   internal error () that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content
>   is not allowed in prolog.
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:527)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   Filter.ThaiRequest.doFilter(ThaiRequest.java:38)
>   org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>
> root cause
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content
>   is not allowed in prolog.
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:858)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:791)
>   org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:101)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   Filter.ThaiRequest.doFilter(ThaiRequest.java:38)
>   org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>
> root cause
>
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content
>   is not allowed in prolog.
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:249)
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.ParseSupport.parseInputSource(ParseSupport.java:227)
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.ParseSupport.parseInputSourceWithFilter(ParseSupport.java:193)
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.ParseSupport.parseReaderWithFilter(ParseSupport.java:199)
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.ParseSupport.parseStringWithFilter(ParseSupport.java:206)
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.ParseSupport.doEndTag(ParseSupport.java:138)
>   org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspx_meth_x_005fparse_005f0(test_jsp.java:150)
>   org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:80)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   Filter.ThaiRequest.doFilter(ThaiRequest.java:38)
>   org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

#### Update:

Now I can read xml with JDOM in servlet but I can't display in jsp file. I can display all data from xml in servlet. I don't know how to display data from title and link tag only in jsp file. please help me.

```
try {

     ReadXMLFile rxml = new ReadXMLFile();
     NodeList nodes = (NodeList) rxml.readXML();
     for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

       /* I can display all data from xml. I want to display data from title and link tag only in JSP file. */
     System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The document at `http://www.manager.co.th/RSS/Home/Breakingnews.xml` looks like it starts with a [Byte-Order-Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

In Java, this is only processed correctly when the XML parser reads directly from the input stream. In your case, though, you're reading the document into a String, and then passing that String to the `<x:parse>` tag, and because it's reading from a String, it doesn't handle the BOM, it thinks it's junk, and gives you the "Content is not allowed in prolog" error.

I don't think this is easily fixable in JSP/JSTL. I think you'll need to either write a custom tag to parse the document direct from the input stream, or use an MVC structure to do the parsing in a servlet/controller, and forward to the JSP for display of the data.